# Protocol moves to another ethx Suse

Tags: linux, nic, sles, protocols

I have a server which has 2 nics eth0 and eth1

eth0 is used for our email traffic server. everything working fine

some time later a eth1 was added for backup purposes so this new nic sends data to another vlan for backup purposes

all of a sudden our mail server starts to fail and we found that protocols or traffic specifically 80 and 8080 is trying to traffic flow using eth1 which is only for backups as I said....

so any idea to link this traffic 80 - 8080 to only eth0?

suse 11

thanks a lot

Comment: are both nics in the same subnet?

Answer (score 1):

Check the routing table on that server, changes are pretty good that either the default route is now pointing to the wrong spot (or is associated with the wrong nic), or there is a static route getting in the way. If it's the default route, that's a fairly quick immediate fix.

SLES stores route information in a few places, but one thing to be sure of is that the backup-network's entry in `/etc/sysconfig/network/ifcfg-eth1` (or whichever it is) isn't listing a gateway.